# osmdroid XYTileSource not showing tiles from the server in Android

Tags: android, dictionary, customization, tiles, osmdroid

I am using OSMdroid apis for the displaying custom tiles. They do provide Google wrapper for the same. So trying to display tiles from my local server

Here is my code

```
final MapTileProviderBasic tileProvider = new MapTileProviderBasic(getApplicationContext());
final ITileSource tileSource = new XYTileSource("SomeName", null, 3, 20, 256, ".png",
                    "http://MyServer/tiles/");
tileProvider.setTileSource(tileSource);
final GoogleTilesOverlay tilesOverlay = new GoogleTilesOverlay(tileProvider, this.getBaseContext());
 mapView.getOverlays().add(tilesOverlay);
```

in the layout I have declared map view in the following way

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/mapview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:apiKey="my API Key"
/>
```

This works fine if I put the tiles under sdcard and use the following code

```
mProvider = new MapTileProviderBasic(getApplicationContext());
mProvider.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.FIETS_OVERLAY_NL);
mTilesOverlay = new GoogleTilesOverlay(mProvider,getParent());
mTilesOverlay.setUseDataConnection(false);
mTilesOverlay.useDataConnection();
mapView.getOverlays().add(mTilesOverlay);
mapView.invalidate();
```

Comment: Have you checked that the url works? (use the url in a browser on the device and make sure a tile is displayed)

Comment: Yes the url works if I put it on browser in the following way http://MyServer/tiles/15/x_y.png

Comment: how about the log files? you need to see what happening when it tries to fetch the tile. Or you could breakpoint the code with debugger to see what happens when it tries to fetch the file. Or you could try using the OSM tile provider.  Can you see the request for the tile in the server logs?

Comment: is my tile naming correct. I created them using maptiles

Comment: good point, my tile server (built using mapnik) uses zoom/x/y.png, I assumed your local copy would use the same as the server.  Checking the server logs will tell you what it asks the server for to confirm this.

Comment: I just found that few of the tile images are not present as per the server logs, but I guess it should show all other images right?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working code for xytilesource hope it might be helpful to someone.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        mapView.getController().setZoom(5);
        GeoPoint point = new LatLonPoint(6.83917,79.91455);
        //mapView.getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(51500000, 5400000));
        mapView.getController().setCenter(point);
        final MapTileProviderBasic tileProvider = new MapTileProviderBasic(getApplicationContext());
        final ITileSource tileSource = new XYTileSource("SomeName", null, 3,14, 256, ".png",
                        "http://192.168.1.5/mapcache/tms/1.0.0/ms-base@GoogleMapsCompatible/");
        //mapView.setTileSource((new XYTileSource("localMapnik", Resource, 0, 18, 256, ".png", 
            //  "http://tile.openstreetmap.org/"))); 
        tileProvider.setTileSource(tileSource);
        final TilesOverlay tilesOverlay = new TilesOverlay(tileProvider, this.getBaseContext());
        mapView.getOverlays().add(tilesOverlay);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private static final class LatLonPoint extends GeoPoint {
        public LatLonPoint(double latitude, double longitude) {
            super((int) (latitude * 1E6), (int) (longitude * 1E6));
        }
    }
```

Layout file should include

```
<org.osmdroid.views.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true" />
```